# Pass upstream url for sub route in Kong

Tags: kong

If I want to make a call to /a/b/c for /a to process the content at /b/c, is there a way to also pass the upstream url for /b/c to /a so /a doesn't need to call back to the original gateway to get the upstream?

Comment: Can you clarify ? which path should be routed to which upstream, and witch upstream info you want to send ?

Comment: for example i have an upstream for /b/c, and i get a request for a/b/c, i want to let the upstream of /a also know the upstream of /b/c by passing a header containing the upstream url of /b/c